# Anyone know of an API for RSI and other indicators?

Tags: api, trading, raw-data

I am looking for Relative Strenght Index and other market indicators API's for cryptos. I don't think TradingView provides one but maybe you know one?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, couldn’t seem to find a good API that supported most of the popular indicators, and at the same time covered all the exchanges. So I decided to start up a project for this. So check out https://taapi.io . We cover 200+ indicators, pattern recognitions etc… I’m a big fan of free products myself, so taapi.io is free as well.

If your indicator isn’t there, then shoot us message, and we’ll get it added!

Comment: Hi Emaix, I saw that you posted about taapi.io twice in your first two answers. Please be sure that you disclose if you're associated with a service that you're recommending: Please check out https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/promotion

Comment: Hi, sorry, my bad. I clearly missed that. I'll revise my answer.

Comment: I think this is just free ad... taapi.io is not so free...

{"errors":["Free plans only permits use of symbols [BTC/USDT,ETH/USDT,XRP/USDT,LTC/USDT,XMR/USDT] from Binance"]}

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate it yourself. Use an API to get the gains and losses over an period of 14 points and put it into the formula described here: http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:relative_strength_index_rsi

Comment: Thanks Futchas, I figured it out on December 28th 2017 but I'll keep your link in my bookmarks!

Comment: @Wizzardzz Good to hear! Can you share with us/me your solution? Since I'm looking for a good why to implement it myself currently

Answer (score 1):

The https://iexcloud.io/ API delivers a powerful toolset with dozens of indicators available. They now support a variety of cryptocurrencies as well. The most cost-effective platform I have seen yet.