# binance advanced indicator api

Tags: api, binance

I know how to extract basic info like bid/ask/open/close prices on binance, but on advanced trading charts on binance I see more price indicators like EMA and I dont want to compute them from price log since they wont be 100% accurate. Is there a way to extract all indicators I see in advanced mode? Can't find any reference in APIs

Answer (score 1):

Use https://taapi.io, there's a bunch of indicators (RSI, MACD, MA, EMA, TD Sequential, ATR, ADX, Bollinger Bands, Momentum, CMF etc...) that you can pull from their API. You can pull indicators from 20 different exchanges or so, including Binance.

Comment: Hi Emax, please take a look [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: Emaix responded very favorably to a similar query on his other question already: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/66738/anyone-know-of-an-api-for-rsi-and-other-indicators/87310#87310, let's give him a moment to revise this one a bit more as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract closing price using "Export As" feature here https://www.coingecko.com/en/price_charts/bitcoin-cash/usd

Comment: unfortunately this method doesnt provide me enough data to compute all indicators I want and even EMA can be only calculated for per-day not per-hour values